# How to describe the various ways in which one can experience something?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word that means "The various manners in which one is able to enjoy, gain fulfillment from, and/or experience a given activity."

For example, you could say "The *<filler noun>* of paper and pencil role-playing games includes the inherent social interaction, applying tactics to combat situations, puzzles, role-playing situations, immersion, and the story." You could also say "Joe appreciates a different part of the *<filler noun>* of clubbing than Susan; he likes to drink and meet new people, but she likes to dress up and be the center of attention."

I think that most activities are probably like this, in that they can be appreciated for different reasons. However, I'd find it useful to also have an adjective that describes how diverse a particular activity's manners of experience are. For example, you could say "Reading is a very *<filler adjective>* activity. It's much more *<filler adjective>* than boxing."

---

**Is there an existing word that conveys the concept that I've described above?**

Slang and short phrases are also acceptable, if there isn't a more formal way to express this concept.

The first thing that I considered was the phrase "diverse experience." However, "experience" does not convey the idea of there being multiple facets to the experience. "Diverse experience" seems to connote instead that the activity might be different every time, rather than that on a single occasion there might be five distinct facets of the activity that can be appreciated.

Comment: @Jon It was only an example to covey his purpose. A thing like MacGuffin!

Comment: I would use "experience" in the first two example sentences.

Comment: That sorta works. The closest phrase that came to mind for me was "Diverse experience" and "diversity of experience" for the last example, though it'd need to be mangled.

Comment: **The word you misheard was surely *panoply*.** (Also:   Please try not to edit your questions to invalidate existing answers based on text that you have since erased.)

Comment: @tchrist that has nothing to do with his question (and did not before his edit, either); and as he already explained, the word he misheard was probably "people playing."

Comment: This is a fun kind of question, trying to figure out third hand from your questionable hearing and memory what someone else _might_ have said. But did you think that maybe a thesaurus might help you? And if it doesn't then all we're going to do is guess. @tchrist is probably right anyway.

Comment: @Mitch - The intent is not to figure out what someone *might* have said, but rather, to find a word that fits the meaning described by the question. I was confused before as to why there was so much focus on figuring out what I heard (when I had asked the speaker what she'd said and received an explanation); I thought it was clear that I wanted a word whose *definition* fit the one that I had come up with for this non-existent word. Now that the question has been edited to not contain any reference to my having misheard something, I'm literally scratching my head in confusion.

Comment: We're all influenced by memory and context. @tchrist's suggestion is probably pretty good without the context of your original 'I heard something like this' example. Also, I suggest 'enriched' or something like that. Still, the difficulty with your question is that we're trying to mind read. Sometimes it works if you can maintain the connection through a reasonable telepathic medium, but a mental block can also be transferred (the difficulties of parapsychology).

Comment: Someone else actually answered with "panoply," but I no longer see the answer below. I imagine they removed it. Regardless, I don't think it fits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps...

> Role playing games offer a [multi-faceted](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/multi+faceted) experience.

I think facet is a good word here; as it describes one aspect (of many) of a thing, it maintains the singularity of the experience.

EDIT: In reading a recent [article](http://www.theamericanconservative.com/jacobs/on-the-powers-and-limits-of-literature/) by Alan Jacobs, a literature professor, about the cumulative impact literature can have on a person, I came across an expression that may be useful in this context. Here is the passage:

> I’ll repeat here, with some emendations, something that I wrote to a friend last night. For most people literature has limited power to do character-shaping because of the limited range of ways it involves the person. (There are of course exceptions to this rule — I think of William Cobbett, for instance, whose whole life was, according to his own account, altered by reading Jonathan Swift. But even then I can’t help thinking that that could only happen because a whole range of complex experiences had prepared him to receive precisely what Swift had to say.)
>
> Various forms of ritual enactment — Yoni Appelbaum is working on some of these matters in his dissertation-in-progress, and I put the point this way after corresponding with him — seem to me to have much greater power because (a) **they engage our [sensorium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensorium) more completely** and (b) they benefit from repetition.

Kinda wordy and high brow, but it seems that the expression is being used to express the variety of ways in which an experience reaches us.

Comment: "Multi-faceted" also works as an adjective in the context above, making it a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

To use your example, you can say that the socializing is a ***"fringe benefit"*** of a role-playing game.

> Definition from Merriam-Webster Online:
>
> 2: any additional benefit (increased energy is a fringe benefit of
>   regular exercise)

Answer (score 0):

An activity that's ***multi-experiential*** can be said to be experienced and appreciated on many levels and (possibly) via several senses.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with *excitement/exciting/exited* or any of the spectacular choices below in italics:

Part of the *excitement* of role-playing games comes from the chance to be *cool* like all the popular kids who do it.

When clubbing with Susan, Joe enjoys different forms of *excitement*.

Reading is pretty *exciting*, much more so than boxing. In fact reading is *awesome*. Whereas boxing is dangerous, reading is *fun*.